# $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ goes to zero as $x\to\infty$, for $F\in L^1([0,\infty))$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function on $[0,\infty)$, such that $f\in L^2([0,\infty))$. Define $F:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ by letting $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ for $x\ge 0$. Assume that $F\in L^1([0,\infty)).$
>
> (a) Prove that $F(x)$ goes to zero as $x\to\infty$.
>
> (b) Replace the assumption that $f\in L^2([0,\infty))$ with the assumption that $f\in L^1([0,\infty))$, and prove that also with this single change on the conditions, $F(x)$ goes to zero as $x\to\infty$.

---

My Thoughts:

First, we prove (b). $$F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$$ is absolutely continuous over $[0,\infty)$ since $f\in L^1([0,\infty))$. It follows that $F(x)$ is Riemann integrable over any finite interval and the Lebesgue integral of $F(x)$ over $[0,\infty)$ is nothing but the improper Riemann integral: $$(R)\int_0^\infty F(x)dx.$$ This can be quickly verified by applying the characteristic function and the dominated convergence theorem. Whence $F(x)$ goes to zero as $x\to\infty$ by the necessarity of existence of improper Riemann integral.

Now, how to prove (a)? Can we just use Hölder's inequality:
$$ \int_0^x|f(t)|dt\le \left(\int_0^xf(t)^2dt\right)^{1/2}\cdot\sqrt{x}<\infty,\quad \forall x>0 $$ to conclude that $F(x)$ is absolutely continuous and use (b)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proof of a): Since $|\int_x^{y} f(t)dt| \leq \sqrt {|x-y|} {\sqrt {\int f^{2}}}$ it follows that $F$ is uniformly continuous. The facts that $F$ is integrable and it is uniformly continuous imply that $F(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. [Proof: if not then there exists $a>0$ and $x _n \to \infty$ such that $|F(x_n)| \geq a$. There exist $\delta >0$ such that $|F(x)-F(y)| <a/2$ for $|x-y| \leq \delta$. Now consider $\int_{x_n}^{x_n+\delta} |F(t)|dt$. This integral is $\geq (a/2) \delta$ since $|F(t)| \geq |F(x_n)| -|F(x)-F(x_n)|$ on the interval $(x_n, x_n+\delta)$. By replacing $(x_n)$ by a subsequence if necessary we can assume that the intervals $(x_n, x_n+\delta)$ are disjoint. Summing the integral of $|F|$ over these intervals we see that $\int |F|=\infty$, a contradiction.